# Custom Text Field Value of Selected Account from Custom Lookup Not Returned in Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lookup, html

I am implementing a custom lookup field in my LWC form. So far, the record is selected properly. I verify it via console.log statement so that I can know if it is really returning any value.

I also wanted to see the `CustomTextField__c` value of the selected account record, but every time I check the logs, it returns `undefined` value. I already assigned a variable that will hold its value, but same result occurs.

Meanwhile, below are the codes I have:

**customLookup html file**

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={childObjectApiName}>
        <label for="fieldid">{fieldLabel}</label>
        <lightning-input-field id="fieldid" required={required} variant="label-hidden" field-name={targetFieldApiName}
            value={value} onchange={handleChange} disabled={disabled}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

**customLookup js file**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomLookup extends LightningElement {
    @api childObjectApiName = 'Case'; 
    @api targetFieldApiName = 'AccountId'; 
    

    @api fieldLabel = 'Your field label here';
 
    @api disabled = false;
    @api value;

    @api required = false;

    handleChange(event) {
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('valueselected', {
            detail: event.detail.value[0]
        });
    
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    @api isValid() {
        if (this.required) {
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field').reportValidity();
        }
    }
}
```

**portion from custom form referencing custom lookup lwc html file**

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
   <div class="slds-var-m-right_small slds-var-m-bottom_medium">
      <c-custom-lookup field-label="Account" 
            child-object-api-name='Case'
            target-field-api-name='AccountId'
            onvalueselected={handleAccountChange}>
      </c-custom-lookup>
   </div>
</div>
```

**portion from custom form js file**

```
@track selectedAccountId; 
@track selectedAccountCustomTextField;

handleAccountChange(event) {
    //this portion works, display expected id of selected record
    this.caseRec.AccountId = event.detail;
    this.selectedAccountId = event.detail;
    console.log('this.selectedAccountId' + this.selectedAccountId);


    //this portion returns undefined    
    this.selectedAccountCustomTextField__c = this.caseRec.Account.CustomTextField__c; 
    console.log('this.selectedAccountCustomTextField' + this.selectedAccountCustomTextField);
}
```

Comment: You'd need to use relationship to get value of the field on Account. Try this.caseRec.Account.CustomTextField__c & it should work.

Comment: @SachinHooda I tried the following but same error occurs: `this.selectedAccountCustomTextField__c = this.caseRec.Account.CustomTextField__c;`

Comment: And does the Account's CustomField__c related to the case has a value?

Comment: Yes, I populated all account records' CustomField__c value before I do my testing in UI.

Comment: Did you queried Account.CustomTextField__c on Case ?

Comment: Oh, I haven't. I thought `CustomTextField__c` can be directly pulled from Parent field using javascript. Do I still need to write Apex ?